# Desencriptar una cadena recibida utilizando llave pública en PHP dentro de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, openssl

Tengo este código para desencriptar una cadena, de hecho dejo también la cadena por si alguien quiere probar.

```php
$str = 'MIIBBgKBgDI/ranPo8MDfguQfSzqg7mtNlUJLLBK7tlVALyk42agbLTSFcZbs9Yw t3nSe9yNzZB9ZVrL3O9GXkEb6xvj3dqrog+wWOeFCqNV7BuJNYYC/ef4vlnUFQdw yswbd7d198qjWBZ7MiZRXxX8qKRln+osTvsDYOMZk93k0cGZgyuJAoGAHkgFohgA nH93kDPjN4sHaT9WsmZ4ailbMtcnWuLizTRJ2sdGjNrpuwT1R+x1nlYHOeDUSOu6 De0kQJX+HZuQCoha6THsdgcV297krN22FwsDZ1PItXLIr5oC7zcNQaDyAJOIv6BC ufHQ0IR+L9b9esniMbF8yV0d7EVAaBJiyRk=';

$Cifrado = base64_decode($str);
openssl_public_decrypt ($Cifrado, $decrypted , file_get_contents('D:/cert.pem'),OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING); 
echo "Data decryption : ".$decrypted;


dd($decrypted);
```

El resultado siempre "da `null`", pero no da error. Es **PHP 7.2**, sobre Windows tiene todas las extensiones necesarias instaladas.

Si a alguien le ha pasado o sabe a qué se debe el error, agradecería pueda ayudarme.

> PD: El resultado deberían ser 4 dígitos ejemplo 0341

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP?

Comment: ¿Podes [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código de como se encripto?

Comment: Alfarobravo en los Log no sale nada de nada, por lo menos de la ejecución de este código.

Comment: Marcos, ahí radica el asunto, solo recibo la cadena encriptado más no tengo accesos a como fue creada.

Comment: @Javier la cadena parece estar encriptada en grupos de 64 bits (_hay espacios cada 64 chars_), pero como dije, parece.... el que te envió la cadena debería explicarte como fue generada

Comment: Buas una funcion propia de laravel?(Dudo que haya) O utilizar PHP? Si es lo ultimo entonces no tendria que estar la etiqueta laravel

Comment: Juan Rivera creo que agregué la etiqueta Laravel porque está dentro de un proyecto Laravel, aunque se que la solución es en php.